# [Kotlin][Best Practice] How to pass receiver object in parameter function's parameter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have below code:

```
internal data class DataClass(
    val name: String
)

internal fun DataClass.defineService() {
    //Some code
    val config = this
    return SomeOtherClassB.someAPI() { () -> 
        createService(config)
    }
}

internal fun SomeOtherClassA.createService(
    config: DataClass
){
    //Some code
}
```

What's the best way to pass DataClass from `defineService()` to `createService()`? I don't want to assign `val config = this`, doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the intermediate variable and put `createService(this@defineService)`.  This allows you to specify the `this` of the scope of `defineService`.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the best way to pass DataClass from defineService() to createService()?

Use a [qualified this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/this-expressions.html#qualified-this) statement:

```
internal fun DataClass.defineService() {
    //Some code
    return SomeOtherClassB.someAPI() { () -> 
        createService(this@defineService)
    }
}
```